# Why are most divisibility exercises only for positive integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been doing some exercises and most of them are about positive integers. Here are a few examples:

(1) Show that if $a,b$ are positive integers then $ab = \gcd(a,b) \text{lcm}(a,b)$.

(2) Let $a,b$ positive integers and $d = \gcd(a,b)$ and $m = \text{lcm}(a,b)$. If $t$ divides both $a$ and $b$ then prove that $t$ divides $d$. If $s$ is a multiple of both $a$ and $b$ show that $s$ is a multiple of $m$.

(3) Let $n$ and $a$ be positve integers and $d=\gcd(a,n)$. Show that the equation $ax \pmod n=  1 $ has a solution if and only if $d=1$.

And so on.

But it seems to me that these statements should also be true for negative integers. For example if $a=-2$ and $b=-3$ then $ab = 6$ and $\gcd(-2, -3) = 1$ and $\text{lcm}(-2,-3) = 6$ so that claim (1) seems to apply also to negative integers.

> What will go wrong in general for negative integers? Do these really
>   only hold for positive integers?

Comment: In divisibility questions, $a$ and $-a$ are essentially the same - any divisor of $a$ is a divisor of $-a$, and any multiple of $a$ is a multiple of $-a$. So we just avoid that ambiguity by sticking with positive integers

Comment: In your example, if we take $a=2$, $b=-3$ then we don't quite get equality. It could all be fixed using an absolute value sign, but that makes things look more complicated for no good reason, since we are primarily interested in non-negative integers.

Comment: Later, in other number systems, you will consider two numbers equivalent for the purpose of divisibility, $a$ and $b$ will be considered the same if $a=bu$ where $u$ is invertible. In the integers, the only invertible elements are $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, "partially ordered sets" make the world a lot simpler.

If you have a relation, like $\mid$, with the following properties, it is a partial order:

1. $a\mid a$
2. $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$ implies $a\mid c$
3. $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ implies $a=b$.

If you have (1) and (2) without (3), you have what is called a "pre-order." A pre-order is just a little messier than an partial order.

The integers under divisibility is a pre-order. The positive integers under divisibility is a partial order.

Every pre-order can be made into a partial order by essentially treating $a,b$ with $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ as "the same." But this requires the notion of equivalence classes, which is probably too far for this answer. In this case, you can define divisibility questions where $n$ and $-n$ are considered the same for all purposes. But the properties of this set of pairs under divisibility is exactly the same as the properties of the positive integers under divisibility, and thus it is much easier to just restrict to those.

When you get to other types of rings, you'll have more complicated sets of elements in each divisibility class.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to work with negative integers, but more care has to be taken. For example, define $\gcd(8,-12)$ as an integer $d$ which is a common divisor of $8$ and $-12$, but which is a multiple of any common divisor of $8$ and $-12$. Then there are *two* possibilities for  $\gcd(8,-12)$, namely $4$ and $-4$. As you see, gcd's and lcm's will generally only be defined up to sign. It's sort of as if you had to say $\sqrt{16} = \pm 4$ all the time.

Comment: Actually $\sqrt{16}$ is just $4$

Comment: @IsuraManchanayake Of course, you're right about that. As a matter of convention, we choose the positive value. But it was an analogy with the kinds of things we'd have to think about if the gcd of two numbers wasn't a fixed number, but instead had two possible values.

Comment: Really depends on definitions, @IsuraManchanayake Usually you are right, $\sqrt{n}$ is defined as a single-valued function on the positive reals. But he's saying **if*** you had to say $\sqrt{16}=\pm 4$ all the time.

Comment: Of course, both these situations actually occur when you move to more generality. In a GCD domain, every two elements has a GCD, but not necessarily a unique GCD, so the GCD function is only determined up to "sign" (a unit). And when one generalizes $x=\sqrt a$ to the solution of an $n$-th degree polynomial, there is no obvious order on the roots so we just take them all (and Galois groups study the symmetries inherent in this representation).